# Как в Atom перейти по имени пространства имён в сам файл?

Tags: atom

В некоторых видео мануалах вижу, как наводя на импортированные классы из пространства имён в редакторе Atom, этот класс становится ссылкой и в этот файл можно перейти.

При помощи какого расширения это можно реализовать?

Или возможно подскажете по какому запросу искать, а то пока не получается найти нужный плагин.

Comment: Большое спасибо) по умолчанию не работал Ctrl+Click. Нашёл, что называется это "go to definition". Установил расширение и всё заработало, супер)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл расширение это, называется Goto Definition

Comment: Как альтернатива: пакет [atom-ide-ui](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui) имеет настройку *Hyperclick*.

Comment: Вот он у меня почему-то постоянно крутит колёсико (вечная загрузка). так ничего не выдаёт(

Comment: Есть такое дело, тоже плююсь) Мне кажется, что  кэширует в памяти при первом обращении.